# Textarea overflows its own width

Tags: html, css

I have a `textarea` within a DIV to ensure a more sensible looking scroll. The only issue is that for some reason the `textarea`, even though set to 100% is wider than the other `name` input.

```css
.half {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-width:5px;  /* Added to show width */
  border-style:dotted; /* Added to show width */
}

input[type=name] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.contain {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    padding: 15px;
    resize: none;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="half">
<form method="post" name="submitted" action="submitted" autocomplete="off">
<input type="name" id="forename" name="forename" placeholder="Forename"><br>
<div class="contain">
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Contact Me" required="">
</form>
</div>
```

The issue can be fixed by removing the `100%` sizing from all width elements of both the `textarea` and the div in which it is contained.

```css
.half {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-width:5px;  /* Added to show width */
  border-style:dotted; /* Added to show width */
}

input[type=name] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.contain {
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

textarea {
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    padding: 15px;
    resize: none;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="half">
<form method="post" name="submitted" action="submitted" autocomplete="off">
<input type="name" id="forename" name="forename" placeholder="Forename"><br>
<div class="contain">
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Contact Me" required="">
</form>
</div>
```

I know that the `textarea` now fills the `.contain` div but my question is why does setting the width 100% actually make it larger than 100% of the width when 100% works perfectly fine on the `name` input. I've solved my issue I think, I just wonder why it occurred in the first place.

Comment: Your first code snippet looks good to me, what's wrong with it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing check this out. Because of the `box-sizing` and the textarea padding the width was `100% + 30px`

Comment: It is fine, just there's overlap with the textarea even though it's sized at 100%. Removing that fixes the issue but then it isn't given min and max sizes which I need. I've added a border to the snippets to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to all elements to include the padding and borders in the width - otherwise those will be *added*  to the `width`, causing the effect you describe.

(Removing the `width: 100%` sets `width` to the default `auto`, which will adjust to borders and paddings)

```css
.half {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

input[type=name] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contain {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    padding: 15px;
    resize: none;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
        border-radius: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="half">
<form method="post" name="submitted" action="submitted" autocomplete="off">
<input type="name" id="forename" name="forename" placeholder="Forename"><br>
<div class="contain">
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Contact Me" required="">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I was just writing the same thing :)

Comment: I don't believe it's an issue with the box sizing because the padding is within the div for that textarea. It seemed to me as though the 100% width was causing it but this has fixed it. My fix in the second snippet worked but I wasn't sure why this was.

Comment: @learningtoanimate For my snippet I took the code of your first snippet, and all I changed was adding `box-sizing: border-box` to all three elements, so this definitely *is* the reason.

Comment: Yeah it is for sure, it just surprised me because I for some reason couldn't figure it out in a way that'd maintain the set widths.

Comment: Just going to add that the height of the textarea needs to be changed by the amount of the padding when box-sizing is used.

Answer (score 0):

Add the css rule

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to the container element

```
<div class="contain">
```

This will Include padding and border in the element's total width and height.

Comment: add it to which element(s)?